# Resize elements in bar chart by multiplying with a factor

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview, oncreate

I am trying to create a bar chart in android where each bar consists of one `View`and one `TextView`.
I add these cells to a `HorizontalScrollView`. This works fine, all my bars appear.

Now I want to resize these bars(as they now all appear in full height) by multiplying them with a factor.

**This is the activity class that i Use.**

```
private ViewGroup linearScrollLayout;
private HorizontalScrollView hScrollView;
private ArrayList<NutrientCell> nutrientsData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.box_plot);
    this.hScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    this.linearScrollLayout = (ViewGroup) this.hScrollView
            .findViewById(R.id.linearScrollLayout);

    try {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        this.nutrientsData = (ArrayList<NutrientCell>) intent
                .getSerializableExtra("nutrientsData");
        //
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    this.initChart();
}

private void initChart() {

    for (NutrientCell c : this.nutrientsData) {

        RelativeLayout rlt = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.hv_boxplot_cell, this.linearScrollLayout, false);

        ((TextView) rlt.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(c
                .getNutrientName().toString());

        View v = ((View) rlt.findViewById(R.id.vv1));
        v.setBackgroundColor(c.getColor());

        this.linearScrollLayout.addView(rlt);
    }

}
```

Now, in the loop found in `initChart()` I iterate over all elements in an `ArrayList`, each of which has a `percentage` variable. This is the variable I would like to multiply the height with.
I have tried to just multiply the height of the LayoutParams of the inflated RelativeLayout found in `initChart` but as this is called in onCreate(), its height property is not correct.

So how can I make sure that the inflated RelativeLayout I add to my View has a height corresponding to the percentage obtained from `c`(`c.getPercentage()`)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the percentage used for? If the percentage is used to scale the view based on it's initial size, you could probably use the view's [setScaleY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleY%28float%29) method to change it's height.